# Max number of LEDs with a given power source and resistors

Tags: led, homework

I had a question about the following problem. I am confused with the number 50. The problems have multiple parts and that's why there are multiple images, and the blue bubble is the answer. Please explain number 50. Thank you so much!
This was my work:
[image: my work]

[image: Other part]

Comment: If you want homework help you need to show your work and explain where you got stuck (which you should do anyway).

Comment: Use ohms law. You have voltage and wattage, and voltage and current

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here. Show your work. Ask a specific question.

Comment: GoldenRetriever - Thanks for adding some details. However, those details are difficult to understand, so it may not help readers to see where you are stuck. For example: What does "x = 2.45 leds" mean? It would likely help readers if you added the units to the values in the formula, to help show what you were trying to calculate. However, personally I recommend you "go up a level" (show methodology before details) i.e. add some words (and perhaps a diagram) to explain your *process* (your *thinking and analysis*) to show how you are trying to approach the problem - before writing a formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the additional questions as all the necessary information is included in number 50.  If you don't provide your own attempt, you get a socratic answer at most.  You seem to be having trouble getting started, so perhaps answer me some questions:

How many 2.5 Voltses can you fit into 6 volts?  How much voltage is left over and how big would the current limiting resistor be for a set of LEDs?  How many watts does that use?  How many times does that fit into 5 watts?  Now that you know how many 6 volt sets of LEDs you need, how many LEDs do you have in total?  Hint, the answer is wrong, but close enough.